Excel VBA Autoformat not passing filter correctly
this is in Excel VBA.
I am trying to set the filter for the list data, as the test i am coding the 07.0 entry to filter on, but the filter is not taking place. If I change the filter to the 20.0.3 or 20.0.1 or any value that was letters in it, it will filter correctly. I will not filter correctly on 07.0, 26.0, or 19.0. this are text based values not numeric.

Here is the code I am using
        With Worksheets("Sheet2")
           lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '~~> Remove any filters
           .AutoFilterMode = False
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "@"
            '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and delete visible rows
        With .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>07.0"
            '.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With```


It's a bug. You would have the same problem doing it manually.
